# C# Generic behavior with C++ Templates

Tags: c#, c++

I'm attempting to port some C# code to C++. I'd like to keep the structure similar, but I realize this might not always be possible.

Based on my research, C++ templates are supposed to be more powerful/flexible than C# Generics, yet I can't seem to recreate a particular behavior.

Here's an overly simplified example of my current C# structure:

```
public class MyGeneric<T>
{
    public void MyTypeSafeMethod(T arg1)
    {
        //logic here
    }
}

public class MyImplA : MyGeneric<MyImplA>
{
    //Class config etc..
}

public class MyImplB : MyGeneric<MyImplB>
{
    //Other config etc...
}

public static class MyCollectionOfGenericImpl
{
    public static MyImplA A = new MyImplA();
    public static MyImplB B = new MyImplB();
}

public class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        //Doesn't compile, method is typesafe 
        MyCollectionOfGenericImpl.A.MyTypeSafeMethod(MyCollectionOfGenericImpl.B);
    }
}
```

As of right now, I don't really see a way to do this using the C++ templates (did some looking at typedef + templates, but I don't see how that will work for me).

Currently, my solution would be to scrap templates completely. I would have a base class (i.e. MyGeneric) with a protected method (i.e. MyTypeSafeMethodProt) that has my logic. I would then expose a new type-safe method in each class implementation that utilizes the protected logic.

Any way to achieve this with templates or another way with less code?

Comment: How can this code compile in C#? You have `public static MyImplA A = new MyImplA();` so `A.MyTypeSafeMethod` would expect `MyImplA` but you're passing `MyImplB`, and they are not compatible!

Comment: See the comment, I say "Doesn't compile", was just trying to prove that this should fail. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Where is your problem exactly porting that to C++ templates? Looks pretty straight forward at first sight.

Comment: @stevem So you want it to not compile?  Second, what have you tried in C++?  I do not know where you ran into a problem.  I assume you know basic differences, such as the fact that class variables in C# correspond to pointers (smart or not) in C++?

Comment: Yes, the problem with C++ is the templates always require a defined type (or my lack of knowledge). As far as I can tell, in C++ you can't define a new class based on a template (i.e. you can't do MyImplA : MyGeneric<MyImplA>). You can do something like typedef vector<int> ListOfInt, but that doesn't help me because I wouldn't having an existing type like int to use.

Comment: It is possible to do exactly what you describe (`class MyImplA : MyGeneric<MyImplA>`) in c++. This idiom is known as [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem at all converting the given code to C++. It is just a syntactical (mechanical) transformation. This reproduces the desired compilation error on the call in the main function.

In short, I’m completely baffled as to what the perceived problem is.

But in the hope that it may help, regardless of problem, here’s corresponding C++ code with the original C# code’s names:

```
template< class T >
struct MyGeneric
{
    void MyTypeSafeMethod( T& arg1 )
    {
        //logic here
    }
};

struct MyImplA : MyGeneric<MyImplA>
{
    //Class config etc..
};

struct MyImplB : MyGeneric<MyImplB>
{
    //Other config etc...
};

struct MyCollectionOfGenericImpl
{
    static MyImplA A;
    static MyImplB B;
};

MyImplA MyCollectionOfGenericImpl::A;
MyImplB MyCollectionOfGenericImpl::B;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    //Doesn't compile, method is typesafe 
    MyCollectionOfGenericImpl::A.MyTypeSafeMethod( MyCollectionOfGenericImpl::B );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was missing the "class" keyword in the definition of my template. I was getting "Type Name Not allowed". I was also using the class instead of struct keyword (can you do the same with class??), and was using headers etc... Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: If you encounter a problem with expressing the static variables A and B in header code, just ask a new question (it's a bit much to discuss in comments).